# Custom post types and custom variables — add_rewrite_tag() not working

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I have spent a whole day trying to resolve in issue. I'm trying to retrieve a custom varaible which is added by my plugin. I have tried testing the regex using the `rewrite analyzer`, which recognizes the regex is correct but when I use it I do not get the expected result

> http://mysite.com/properties/property/2/

should return a var of `property_id = 2`, but this is nowhere to be found in `var_dump($wp_query->query_vars)`;

Any Ideas?

```
public function __construct()
        {
            // register actions
          add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'admin_init'));
        } // END public function __construct
public function admin_init()
        {
$pholderid = 4;
add_rewrite_tag('%property_id%', '([^&]+)');
          add_rewrite_tag('%psearchparam%', '([^&]+)');
          $pholderid = get_option( 'vvpp_post_id' );            
          if (isset($pholderid)){
          //use placeholder to identify property details as post
          add_rewrite_rule("properties/property/([0-9]{1,})/([^/]*)/?",'index.php?post_type=properties&p='.$pholderid.'&property_id=$matches[1]','top');
          add_rewrite_rule("properties/property/([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=properties&p='.$pholderid.'&property_id=$matches[1]','top');
          }
          add_rewrite_rule("properties/page/([0-9]{1,})/([^/]*)/?",'index.php?post_type=properties&paged=$matches[1]&psearchparam=$matches[2]','top');        
          //might be needed
          flush_rewrite_rules();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the rewrite tag on `admin_init`, so it doesn't exist on front end requests. Add your rewrite stuff on `init` instead.

Comment: Perfect. Sorry for the noob question. couldn't see for looking, sometimes need fresh eyes.